# Print a line in python up to a space

Tags: python

If I have two separate values in a line like this:

```
1234556 1234567
```

How would I go about printing out both numbers in two separate variables?

The digits lengths will change per line so i cant simply search index the line.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
s = "1234556 1234567"
a, b = map(int, s.split(' '))
print a, b
```